# Blank page on search

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I often get a completely blank page when I perform a search on Stack Overflow.

This occurs when there should definitely be results.  For instance, I just searched iPhone :-p

The results show up briefly and then disappear.  This happens with Safari as well as FireFox.

Usually, this condition just fixes itself in 30 minutes or so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are searching for something in your "ignored tags" list and you have ticked the "hide ignored tags" preference on your preference page.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks Jeff.
The funny thing was, I could have sworn I removed the "ignored tag" from the list prior to doing the search.  
Can I recommend that you show something in the search result area on the right, like "765 ignored questions"