# Why is a specific search resulting in a blank question list?

Tags: support, search, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank page on search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53015/blank-page-on-search)

When I search for "`subversion vs git`" on StackOverflow, the results show up, then are shortly replaced by blank space.

Other searches are working OK. This is the first search where I am having this problem.

The page numbers for questions are still present, but no questions are listed.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Would it be beneficial to display a small message that no results occurred due to you ignoring these specific tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have either [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) or [git](/questions/tagged/git) in your Ignored Tags, and have the "Hide Ignored Tags" checkbox checked in your profile.

Comment: I feel rather silly now, that's what it was. Thanks!