# Warning for when no questions are shown due to ignored tags?

Tags: feature-request, search

I feel silly now, after [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74300/why-is-a-specific-search-resulting-in-a-blank-question-list)...

Would it be difficult to add a message of some kind when *no* results are shown after a search because all questions have a tag in the users ignored tag list?

Something like `"You have ignored one or more tags in all search results..."` -- if nothing else, it would save a bit of time figuring out what went wrong. :)

Related questions:

- ["Hide ignored tags" should retrieve more questions to fill up the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9787/hide-ignored-tags-should-retrieve-more-questions-to-fill-up-the-page)
- [Don't hide questions when browsing an ignored tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36857/dont-hide-questions-when-browsing-an-ignored-tag)