# "new" and/or "no answer" listing for recent, large  filter sets return nothing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-filters

Some large-ish [filters (tag sets) of Stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6714387), grouping favorite tags of mine, (erroneously) don't return anything if I ask for 'newest' or 'no answers' sorting. For instance:

- [This one](https://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/favorite-tags?sort=noanswers) doesn't return anything for "no answers" (but it should return, e.g. : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047366))
- [That one](https://stackexchange.com/filters/13013/favorite-tags?sort=newest) doesn't return anything for either "newest" or "no answers"

I'm not subscribed to email notices for those tagsets, so i can't tell if they have stopped coming, but the corresponding RSS feeds are empty. I have tried updating "my favorite tags", using `https://stackexchange.com/filters/re-sync/<filterid>` while logged in, to no avail (it generated a tag set whose "newest" and "no answer" sorts display nothing). This led me to think that those sorts ("newest", "no answers") are not handled/computed/updated for newly created tagsets, is that true ?

- Edit (07/17 06:00 UTC): Now I have nothing for ["newest" for the first filter either](https://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/favorite-tags?sort=newest).
- Edit (07/17 15:15 UTC): Now "newest" sorting is back for the first filter (link on the line above). The second filter set consistently has "newest" and "no answers" sorting off, though.

Comment: “Only questions with activity in the last 14 days are included in results.”, so the first shouldn't include your example, but it should include e.g. [OpenCL executing without input data or using 3 dimensions.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6714387). I see no hit on http://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/favorite-tags?sort=noanswers either.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the counter-example question. I also updated links to tagsets to point to noanswers/newest sorting.

Answer (score 2):

In both of the links provided, I see several results.  Is this possibly a case of [hiding ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53015/blank-page-on-search)?

Comment: The link isn't to the “no answers” sorting, do you get resulsts on http://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/favorite-tags?sort=noanswers ?

Comment: No.  But I do see pages of results when sorting by 'newest'.  That listing includes [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716667) which should show up under 'no-answers'.  That sorting tab does appear broken.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned the first tagset returns results for "noanswers". But the second doesn't: I bet you can't see results on http://stackexchange.com/filters/13013/favorite-tags?sort=newest

Comment: Correct.  I don't see anything there either.

Answer (score 0):

After a recent round of improvements to the SQL query backing filters, large-ish filters such as [the](https://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/favorite-tags?sort=noanswers) [ones](https://stackexchange.com/filters/13013/favorite-tags?sort=newest) [linked](https://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/favorite-tags?sort=newest) to in this question aren't erroring any more.