# Filter show always 0 results even when results are available

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I created [this](https://stackexchange.com/filters/18155/coding) filter. As i understand, the filter should show any questions tagged with any of `ruby*`, `python*`, `mysql*`, `sqlite*`.

It used to work ok until a few days ago. Now it always show 0 unanswered questions in the last 14 days, which is not true, if i do a filter containing only one tag, like `ruby*` or any other it work as expected.

And idea why this particular combination do not work?

Comment: I seems to work for me: http://stackexchange.com/filters/9965/my-filter

Comment: it fail with the particular combination of tags i listed. If i try one by one, it work ok.

Comment: even the one you put there works completely fine.

Comment: This seems eerily similar to [this previous issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98695/new-and-or-no-answer-listing-for-recent-large-filter-sets-return-nothing).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you simply need to click on [active](https://stackexchange.com/filters/18040/coding?sort=active) or [hot](https://stackexchange.com/filters/18040/coding?sort=hot).

However, I also don't see any questions on either the [newest](https://stackexchange.com/filters/18040/coding?sort=newest) or [no answers](https://stackexchange.com/filters/18040/coding?sort=noanswers) tabs.

**Which seems more than a little odd given the tags.**

Comment: That's the problem actually. If i set a filter with some of the tags i got results for **newest** and **no answers** tabs but with all that 4 always 0.

Answer (score 0):

Filters with wildcard tags end up being relatively taxing on our database. But we've just made  some optimizations to our filters SQL query so largish filters such as this one are returning in a reasonable amount of time now.