# "Filtered Questions" returns no results for filter with lots of wildcards

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

As can be seen [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/35471/vcs?sort=active) and [here](https://stackexchange.com/filters/35471/vcs?sort=newest), pages (for *my* saved filter) are always empty.

PS: [“new” and/or “no answer” listing for recent, large filter sets return nothing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98695/new-and-or-no-answer-listing-for-recent-large-filter-sets-return-nothing) question is known and filter re-checked with new URL (no luck) https://stackexchange.com/filters/35471/favorite-tags?sort=

Comment: Well, it *should* work, so my only guess is it fails due to too many tags/results which cause a timeout on the server side.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - output is always 100 questions, to many results doesn't play. Too many tags? http://stackexchange.com/filters/2923/ (which work) have 69 tags on 3 sites, my filter - 14 at all... And **"no answers" (with additional condition on top) show (!!!) results**

Comment: Well, you got many wildcards, something there is probably more complicated than plain 69 tags. Like I said, agree it's a bug, only a dev can give full answer and possible fix this.