# Getting blank screen on the following search w/ Chrome

Tags: support, search, ignored-tags, google-chrome, page-rendering

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Results on search page disappear after page load](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97396/results-on-search-page-disappear-after-page-load)
>   [Blank page on search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53015/blank-page-on-search)

In chrome v 12.0.742.122 if I open this search I get a page that clearly has search results, yet the questions are not visible.

Seems to be a CSS/Javascript issue

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+static+analysis+tools

Comment: Do you have the [tag:c++] tag ignored, and the "hide ignored questions" preference checked in your profile?

Comment: you're right @Tim, @Scott edited my answer

Comment: Yes, same problem as discussed here: [Results on search page disappear after page load](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97396/results-on-search-page-disappear-after-page-load)

Answer (score 3):

Works for me [image] (all are ignored from my side, though)

My version is 12.0.742.122 (same as yours).

Problem is that you have c++ tag ignored and you have "hide ignored tags" in your profile prefs enabled
[image][image]

Make sure it's not checked

Comment: I don't have any problem either, on Mac OS X, and with Google Chrome 12.0.742.122.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 (Ultimate edition)

Comment: answer edited, I know reason